# GCM pushnotification using urban airship library

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

After changing the sender id ,push notification feature is not working in my application. I have configured urban airship account with new API key and modified code with new sender id.

Is there anymore thing to when changing sender id? Is there any delay with Urban airship push notification service when account is modified? Can any one suggest an official documentation regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This issue happened because there is a delay with urban airship push notification service after modifying sender id. The thing worked fine after a day. 
>   There is a remark in urban airship support documentation regarding this. 
>   https://support.urbanairship.com/customer/portal/articles/823114-gcm-troubleshooting-guide

Thanks,

Comment: The support link doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not working when you're trying to send messages to registration ids that were created for the old sender id, the reason for it is that those registration ids work only with the old sender id and old Api key.

You should make sure that your app re-registers to gcm with the new sender id and gets a new registration id. It's possible that you cache the old registration id and don't get a new one.